# Transposing an Excel sheet with pandas adding additional information for a different readability - Using Fake Pizzeria Data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The goal is to transpose the excel file that comes in the following form

[image]

into this

[image]

The code I created works properly, but I think it can be improved.

I would also like to avoid using `reduce` to avoid importing `functools`.

```
#importing the libraries
import pandas as pd 
from functools import reduce
 
#defining the mapping list
descriptions_pizzeria = [
     "Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli",
     "Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma",
     "Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna",
     "Pizzeria Da Michele - Londra",
     ]

pizzeria_code = [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
                  ]

#path where the data are stored
url_path = "https://github.com/uomodellamansarda/AC_StackQuestions/blob/main/Pizzerie.xlsx?          raw=true"                 
#reading the data
df = pd.read_excel(url_path,  index_col=0, header=3)

#printing to have an idea
print(df)

#from an inspection we now that 
#the first column is where the Pizzeria code is stored
#but we need to rename it
#we need to rename the first column
df = df.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 1":"Pizzeria code"})

print(df.info())

#Grouping based on the pizzeria code
G = df.groupby('Pizzeria code')

pizzeria_df_list = []

for i, code in enumerate(pizzeria_code):
      #selecting the related Pizzeria commercial name
       description = descriptions_pizzeria[i]

       df_temp = G.get_group(code)
       #Dropping and trasposing the Pizzeria Code column
       df_temp = df_temp.drop(columns="Pizzeria code").transpose()
       #Based on what we know about the columns we can create the suffix
       col_suffix = ['Average Values', '# of customers ', 'Servings']
       #and rename the columns 
       df_temp.columns = [description + "_" + x for x in col_suffix]

       pizzeria_df_list.append(df_temp)
pizzeria_df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y,right_index=True, left_index=True), pizzeria_df_list)

pizzeria_df.to_excel("Pizzeria_trasposed.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Instead of looping through each pizzeria and merging temporary subframes, it's more idiomatic to manipulate/map the columns at once.

The bulk of the work is just changing the original columns (left) to be filled/dropped/sorted/renamed (right):

```
       FROM THESE                            TO THESE                     
|----------------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|  Category  Pizzeria  |        Category                       Pizzeria  |
|     Sales       NaN  |                                                 |
|       NaN       1.0  |  Average Values   Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli  |
|       NaN       2.0  |  # of Customers   Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli  |
|       NaN       3.0  |        Servings   Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli  |
|    People       NaN  |                                                 |
|       NaN       1.0  |  Average Values     Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma  |
|       NaN       2.0  |  # of Customers     Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma  |
|       NaN       3.0  |        Servings     Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma  |
|    Dishes       NaN  |                                                 |
|       NaN       1.0  |  Average Values  Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna  |
|       NaN       2.0  |  # of Customers  Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna  |
|       NaN       3.0  |        Servings  Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna  |
|----------------------|-------------------------------------------------|
```

```
df = pd.read_excel(url_path, header=3)
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Category', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Pizzeria'})

# fill the null categories
df['Category'] = df['Category'].ffill()

# group up the pizzerias
df = df.dropna().sort_values('Pizzeria')

# map to the preferred pizzeria names
df['Pizzeria'] = df['Pizzeria'].map({
    1: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli',
    2: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma',
    3: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna',
    4: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Londra',
})

# map to the preferred category names
df['Category'] = df['Category'].map({
    'Dishes': 'Servings',
    'People': '# of Customers',
    'Sales': 'Average Values',
})

# set the combined pizzeria_category as the index
df = df.set_index(['Pizzeria', 'Category'])
df.index = [f'{p}_{c}' for p, c in df.index]  # or ['_'.join(i) for i in df.index]

# transpose and output
df.T.to_excel('Pizzeria_transposed.xlsx')
```

Output:

```
                     Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -   Pizzeria Da Michele -   Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -
                     Napoli_Average Values  Napoli_# of Customers        Napoli_Servings    Roma_Average Values    Roma_# of Customers          Roma_Servings  Bologna_Average Values  Bologna_# of Customers       Bologna_Servings
2021-11-01 00:00:00                  100.0                   70.0                   10.0                  300.0                  200.0                   30.0                    50.0                    20.0                    5.0 
2021-11-08 00:00:00                  250.0                  160.0                   25.0                  350.0                  150.0                   35.0                   100.0                    70.0                   10.0 
2021-11-15 00:00:00                  100.0                   70.0                   10.0                  500.0                  300.0                   50.0                   250.0                   160.0                   25.0 
2021-11-22 00:00:00                  300.0                  200.0                   30.0                 2000.0                 1000.0                  200.0                    10.0                    20.0                    1.0 
2021-11-29 00:00:00                  400.0                  250.0                   40.0                 1000.0                  500.0                  100.0                   300.0                   200.0                   30.0
```

---

### Detailed breakdown

1. Load the excel sheet without setting `index_col` because it will be easier to manipulate the `Category` as a column rather than index:

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel(url_path, header=3)
   df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Category', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Pizzeria'})

   #    Category  Pizzeria  2021-11-01 00:00:00  2021-11-08 00:00:00  2021-11-15 00:00:00  2021-11-22 00:00:00  2021-11-29 00:00:00
   # 0     Sales       NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN
   # 1       NaN       1.0                100.0                250.0                100.0                300.0                400.0
   # 2       NaN       2.0                300.0                350.0                500.0               2000.0               1000.0
   # 3       NaN       3.0                 50.0                100.0                250.0                 10.0                300.0
   # 4    People       NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN
   # 5       NaN       1.0                 70.0                160.0                 70.0                200.0                250.0
   # 6       NaN       2.0                200.0                150.0                300.0               1000.0                500.0
   # 7       NaN       3.0                 20.0                 70.0                160.0                 20.0                200.0
   # 8    Dishes       NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN
   # 9       NaN       1.0                 10.0                 25.0                 10.0                 30.0                 40.0
   # 10      NaN       2.0                 30.0                 35.0                 50.0                200.0                100.0
   # 11      NaN       3.0                  5.0                 10.0                 25.0                  1.0                 30.0
   ```
2. [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) (forward-fill) the null `Category` values and then sort by `Pizzeria` so that the pizzerias are grouped up:

   ```
   df['Category'] = df['Category'].ffill()
   df = df.dropna().sort_values('Pizzeria')

   #    Category  Pizzeria  2021-11-01 00:00:00  2021-11-08 00:00:00  2021-11-15 00:00:00  2021-11-22 00:00:00  2021-11-29 00:00:00
   # 1     Sales       1.0                100.0                250.0                100.0                300.0                400.0
   # 5    People       1.0                 70.0                160.0                 70.0                200.0                250.0
   # 9    Dishes       1.0                 10.0                 25.0                 10.0                 30.0                 40.0
   # 2     Sales       2.0                300.0                350.0                500.0               2000.0               1000.0
   # 6    People       2.0                200.0                150.0                300.0               1000.0                500.0
   # 10   Dishes       2.0                 30.0                 35.0                 50.0                200.0                100.0
   # 3     Sales       3.0                 50.0                100.0                250.0                 10.0                300.0
   # 7    People       3.0                 20.0                 70.0                160.0                 20.0                200.0
   # 11   Dishes       3.0                  5.0                 10.0                 25.0                  1.0                 30.0
   ```
3. [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) `Pizzeria` and `Category` to your preferred strings:

   ```
   df['Pizzeria'] = df['Pizzeria'].map({
       1: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli',
       2: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma',
       3: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna',
       4: 'Pizzeria Da Michele - Londra',
   })
   df['Category'] = df['Category'].map({
       'Dishes': 'Servings',
       'People': '# of Customers',
       'Sales': 'Average Values',
   })

   #           Category                       Pizzeria  2021-11-01 00:00:00  2021-11-08 00:00:00  2021-11-15 00:00:00  2021-11-22 00:00:00  2021-11-29 00:00:00
   # 1   Average Values   Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli                100.0                250.0                100.0                300.0                400.0
   # 5   # of Customers   Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli                 70.0                160.0                 70.0                200.0                250.0
   # 9         Servings   Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli                 10.0                 25.0                 10.0                 30.0                 40.0
   # 2   Average Values     Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma                300.0                350.0                500.0               2000.0               1000.0
   # 6   # of Customers     Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma                200.0                150.0                300.0               1000.0                500.0
   # 10        Servings     Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma                 30.0                 35.0                 50.0                200.0                100.0
   # 3   Average Values  Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna                 50.0                100.0                250.0                 10.0                300.0
   # 7   # of Customers  Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna                 20.0                 70.0                160.0                 20.0                200.0
   # 11        Servings  Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna                  5.0                 10.0                 25.0                  1.0                 30.0
   ```
4. Join `Pizzeria` and `Category` inside the index (either explicitly unpack+concat the tuples or [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them):

   ```
   df = df.set_index(['Pizzeria', 'Category'])
   df.index = [f'{p}_{c}' for p, c in df.index]  # or ['_'.join(i) for i in df.index]

   #                                               2021-11-01 00:00:00  2021-11-08 00:00:00  2021-11-15 00:00:00  2021-11-22 00:00:00  2021-11-29 00:00:00
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli_Average Values                 100.0                250.0                100.0                300.0                400.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli_# of Customers                  70.0                160.0                 70.0                200.0                250.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Napoli_Servings                        10.0                 25.0                 10.0                 30.0                 40.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma_Average Values                   300.0                350.0                500.0               2000.0               1000.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma_# of Customers                   200.0                150.0                300.0               1000.0                500.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Roma_Servings                          30.0                 35.0                 50.0                200.0                100.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna_Average Values                 50.0                100.0                250.0                 10.0                300.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna_# of Customers                 20.0                 70.0                160.0                 20.0                200.0
   # Pizzeria Da Michele - Bologna_Servings                        5.0                 10.0                 25.0                  1.0                 30.0
   ```
5. Finally transpose and save:

   ```
   df.T.to_excel('Pizzeria_transposed.xlsx')

   #                      Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -   Pizzeria Da Michele -   Pizzeria Da Michele -  Pizzeria Da Michele -
   #                      Napoli_Average Values  Napoli_# of Customers        Napoli_Servings    Roma_Average Values    Roma_# of Customers          Roma_Servings  Bologna_Average Values  Bologna_# of Customers       Bologna_Servings
   # 2021-11-01 00:00:00                  100.0                   70.0                   10.0                  300.0                  200.0                   30.0                    50.0                    20.0                    5.0 
   # 2021-11-08 00:00:00                  250.0                  160.0                   25.0                  350.0                  150.0                   35.0                   100.0                    70.0                   10.0 
   # 2021-11-15 00:00:00                  100.0                   70.0                   10.0                  500.0                  300.0                   50.0                   250.0                   160.0                   25.0 
   # 2021-11-22 00:00:00                  300.0                  200.0                   30.0                 2000.0                 1000.0                  200.0                    10.0                    20.0                    1.0 
   # 2021-11-29 00:00:00                  400.0                  250.0                   40.0                 1000.0                  500.0                  100.0                   300.0                   200.0                   30.0
   ```

Comment: Nice explanation and definitely more pandas-idiomatic. I would suggest in step 3, `dict(enumerate(descriptions_pizzeria, 1))` is maybe a bit too clever, and instead `descriptions_pizzeria` should be merged with `pizzeria_code` and become a simple dictionary or intenum, mapping location codes to strings. This way the correspondence is explicit so you don't end up accidentally adding a name to the wrong index in the list and making the auto mapping invalid, if that makes sense. Also more efficient at runtime to predefine this.

Comment: Also in section 4 `df.index = ['_'.join(i) for i in df.index]` maybe do a tuple unpacking to make it more explicit, e.g. `df.index = [f"{pizzeria}_{sales_category}" for pizzeria, sales_category in df.index]` - it's less performant than your approach but a lot clearer I think and this is not a performance bottleneck in the code so I'd take that trade-off :). Subjective though...

Comment: @Greedo Thanks for the feedback! Great points -- will update.